# RecyclerView does show items when scroll is used

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a weird problem on Android 11 and SDK30.

I load data from the web and put them into the adapter. The adapter is set, recyclerview is invalidated(), even tried forceLayout() but in some cases the fields are not showing up.

When I touch the screen and try to scroll the recyclerview the data appears.

I tried everything now. Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), etc.... but nothing works.

As mentioned below in my comment, here is the billing library handler code, which messing up the fragments refreshes. Not clear why.

```
class SubscriptionHandler : PurchasesUpdatedListener, WebHelper.WebHelperDelegate {
interface SubscriptionHandlerDelegate {
    fun skuDetailsAvailable(skuDetails: MutableList<SkuDetails>)
    fun purchaseSuccess(productID: String, prevProductID: String, purchaseToken: String)
    fun purchaseFailed(productID: String, prevProductID: String)
}

private var billingClient: BillingClient? = null
private var context: Context
private var actProduct: String = ""
private var prevProduct: String = ""
var delegate: SubscriptionHandlerDelegate? = null

constructor (_context: Context) {
    context = _context
    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(context)
        .enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this).build()

    billingClient!!.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
        override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                mainAct?.runOnUiThread {
                    billingClient!!.queryPurchasesAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS) { billingResults, queryPurchases ->
                        //val queryPurchase =
                        //    billingClient!!.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)
                        //val queryPurchases = queryPurchase.purchasesList
                        if (queryPurchases.size > 0) {
                            handlePurchases(queryPurchases)
                        }

                        //check which items are in purchase list and which are not in purchase list
                        //if items that are found add them to purchaseFound
                        //check status of found items and save values to preference
                        //item which are not found simply save false values to their preference
                        //indexOf return index of item in purchase list from 0-2 (because we have 3 items) else returns -1 if not found
                        val purchaseFound = ArrayList<Int>()
                        if (queryPurchases.size > 0) {
                            //check item in purchase list
                            for (p in queryPurchases) {
                                for (sku in p.skus) {
                                    val index = subcribeItemIDs.indexOf(sku)
                                    //if purchase found
                                    if (index > -1) {
                                        purchaseFound.add(index)
                                        if (p.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
                                            NotificationsPurchased = true
                                            NotificationsProductID = sku
                                            NotificationsPurchaseToken =
                                                p.purchaseToken
                                            SideNavView?.menu?.findItem(R.id.nav_notifications)?.isEnabled =
                                                true
                                            SideNavView?.invalidate()
                                            SideNavView?.forceLayout()
                                        } else {
                                            delSubscriptions()
                                            NotificationsPurchased = false
                                            NotificationsProductID = ""
                                            NotificationsPurchaseToken = ""
                                            SideNavView?.menu?.findItem(R.id.nav_notifications)?.isEnabled =
                                                false
                                            SideNavView?.invalidate()
                                            SideNavView?.forceLayout()
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //if purchase list is empty that means no item is not purchased/Subscribed
                        //Or purchase is refunded or canceled
                        //so mark them all false
                        else {
                            for (purchaseItem in subcribeItemIDs) {
                                delSubscriptions()
                                NotificationsPurchased = false
                                NotificationsProductID = ""
                                NotificationsPurchaseToken = ""
                                SideNavView?.menu?.findItem(R.id.nav_notifications)?.isEnabled =
                                    false
                                SideNavView?.invalidate()
                                SideNavView?.forceLayout()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {}
    })

}

fun initiatePurchase(PRODUCT_ID: String) {
    actProduct = PRODUCT_ID
    prevProduct = ""
    val skuList: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    skuList.add(PRODUCT_ID)
    val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)
    val billingResult =
        billingClient!!.isFeatureSupported(BillingClient.FeatureType.SUBSCRIPTIONS)
    if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
        billingClient!!.querySkuDetailsAsync(
            params.build()
        ) { billingResult, skuDetailsList ->
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                if (skuDetailsList != null && skuDetailsList.size > 0) {
                    val flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                        .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList[0])
                        .build()
                    mainAct?.runOnUiThread {
                        billingClient!!.launchBillingFlow(context as Activity, flowParams)
                    }
                } else {
                    //try to add item/product id "s1" "s2" "s3" inside subscription in google play console
                    mainAct?.runOnUiThread {
                        delegate?.purchaseFailed(PRODUCT_ID, "")
                        Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            "Hiba! Előfizetés nem található!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                }
            } else {
                mainAct?.runOnUiThread {
                    delegate?.purchaseFailed(PRODUCT_ID, "")
                    Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        " Hiba! Vásárlás nem lehetséges!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        mainAct?.runOnUiThread {
            delegate?.purchaseFailed(PRODUCT_ID, "")
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "Hiba! Előfizetés nem támogatott!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }
}

fun changePurchase(PRODUCT_ID: String, prevProductID: String, prevToken: String) {
    actProduct = PRODUCT_ID
    prevProduct = prevProductID
    val skuList: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    skuList.add(PRODUCT_ID)
    val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)
    val billingResult =
        billingClient!!.isFeatureSupported(BillingClient.FeatureType.SUBSCRIPTIONS)
    if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
        billingClient!!.querySkuDetailsAsync(
            params.build()
        ) { billingResult, skuDetailsList ->
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                if (skuDetailsList != null && skuDetailsList.size > 0) {
                    val flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                        .setSubscriptionUpdateParams( BillingFlowParams.SubscriptionUpdateParams.newBuilder()
                            .setOldSkuPurchaseToken(prevToken)
                            .setReplaceSkusProrationMode(BillingFlowParams.ProrationMode.IMMEDIATE_WITH_TIME_PRORATION)
                            .build())
                        .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList[0])
                        .build()
                    mainAct?.runOnUiThread {
                        billingClient!!.launchBillingFlow(context as Activity, flowParams)
                    }
                } else {
                    //try to add item/product id "s1" "s2" "s3" inside subscription in google play console
                        mainAct?.runOnUiThread {
                            delegate?.purchaseFailed(actProduct, prevProduct)
                            Toast.makeText(
                                context,
                                " Hiba! Előfizetés módosítás sikertelen!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }
                }
            } else {
                mainAct?.runOnUiThread {
                    delegate?.purchaseFailed(actProduct, prevProduct)
                    Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        " Hiba! Előfizetés módosítás sikertelen!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        mainAct?.runOnUiThread {
            delegate?.purchaseFailed(actProduct, prevProduct)
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "Hiba! Előfizetés nem támogatott!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }
}

fun getSkuDetails() {
    val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
    params.setSkusList(subcribeItemIDs).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)

    val billingResult =
        billingClient!!.isFeatureSupported(BillingClient.FeatureType.SUBSCRIPTIONS)
    if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
        billingClient!!.querySkuDetailsAsync(
            params.build()
        ) { billingResult, skuDetailsList ->
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                if (skuDetailsList != null && skuDetailsList.size > 0) {
                    delegate?.skuDetailsAvailable(skuDetailsList)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onPurchasesUpdated(billingResult: BillingResult, purchases: List<Purchase>?) {
    //if item newly purchased
    if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
        handlePurchases(purchases)
    } else if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
        billingClient!!.queryPurchasesAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS) { billingResults, queryPurchases ->
            queryPurchases?.let { handlePurchases(it) }
        }
    } else if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
        mainAct?.runOnUiThread {
            delegate?.purchaseFailed(actProduct, prevProduct)
            Toast.makeText(context, "Előfizetés megszakítva", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    } else {
        mainAct?.runOnUiThread {
            delegate?.purchaseFailed(actProduct, prevProduct)
            Toast.makeText(context, "Hiba! Előfizetés nem lehetséges!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        }
    }
}

private fun handlePurchases(purchases: List<Purchase>) {
    for (purchase in purchases) {
        for (sku in purchase.skus) {
            val index = subcribeItemIDs.indexOf(sku)
            //purchase found
            if (index > -1) {
                //if item is purchased
                if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
                    if (!verifyValidSignature(purchase.originalJson, purchase.signature)) {
                        // Invalid purchase
                        // show error to user
                        mainAct?.runOnUiThread {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                context,
                                "Hiba! Előfizetés nem lehetséges!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                            delegate?.purchaseFailed(actProduct, prevProduct)
                        }
                        continue  //skip current iteration only because other items in purchase list must be checked if present
                    }
                    // else purchase is valid
                    //if item is purchased/subscribed and not Acknowledged
                    if (!purchase.isAcknowledged) {
                        val acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                            .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
                            .build()
                        billingClient!!.acknowledgePurchase(
                            acknowledgePurchaseParams
                        ) { billingResult ->
                            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                                //if purchase is acknowledged
                                //then saved value in preference
                                saveSubscription(purchase.purchaseToken, sku)
                                //saveSubscribeItemValueToPref(subcribeItemIDs[index], true)
                                mainAct?.runOnUiThread {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                        context,
                                        "Vásárlás sikeres",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                    )
                                        .show()
                                }
                                delegate?.purchaseSuccess(
                                    actProduct,
                                    prevProduct,
                                    purchase.purchaseToken
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Grant entitlement to the user on item purchase
                        delegate?.purchaseSuccess(
                            actProduct,
                            prevProduct,
                            purchase.purchaseToken
                        )
                        saveSubscription(purchase.purchaseToken, sku)
                    }
                } else if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PENDING) {
                    mainAct?.runOnUiThread {
                        delegate?.purchaseFailed(actProduct, prevProduct)
                        Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            " Várakozó előfizetése van! Kérjük véglegesítse a várakozó előfizetését!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                } else if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.UNSPECIFIED_STATE) {
                    //mark purchase false in case of UNSPECIFIED_STATE
                    //saveSubscribeItemValueToPref(subcribeItemIDs[index], false)
                    mainAct?.runOnUiThread {
                        delegate?.purchaseFailed(actProduct, prevProduct)
                        Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            " Előfizetési állapot nem értelmezhető!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun verifyValidSignature(signedData: String, signature: String): Boolean {
    return try {
        //for old playconsole
        // To get key go to Developer Console > Select your app > Development Tools > Services & APIs.
        //for new play console
        //To get key go to Developer Console > Select your app > Monetize > Monetization setup
        val base64Key =
            "my security code is here"
        Security.verifyPurchase(base64Key, signedData, signature)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        false
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting story, can you share some code? I have no issues so far.

Comment: Hi, I have figured out that all these weird things are happening due to changing from Billing library 3.0.3 to 4.0.0. I have moved my billing setup code to be running from the fragment, where I load the data to the recycler view and it works well now. But still have issue to get a menu item enabled once a purchase is done. If I move to another fragment it is enabled, but not in the same fragment. So I cannot move directly to that other fragment which supposed to be enabled when a subscription is made. This is also randomly enabled or not after subscription made.